# What is Play 2.0 FakeApplication's url address

Tags: playframework-2.0

In a functional test, what is the actual address for fakeApplication()?

```
@Test
public void findById() {
  running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Computer macintosh = Computer.find.byId(21l);
      assertThat(macintosh.name).isEqualTo("Macintosh");
      assertThat(formatted(macintosh.introduced)).isEqualTo("1984-01-24");
    }
  });
}
```

**EDIT**

Andy's answers works for me.

```
@Test
public void findById() {
  running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3333/endpoint");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICT, if you need an url you should use a FakeServer instead of a FakeApplication